# Dbcontext object not reading int.Parse

Tags: c#

Whenever I click the myScoresButton I get a format exception error. Here's a screenshot of the error and code.
http://postimg.org/image/5bjqqgcnx/full/
How can I resolve this?

```
 int num = 2;
 easyScoreLabel.Text = num.ToString(); 
message aMessage = new message();
aMessage.userName = nameTextBox.Text;
aMessage.highScoreEasy = Int32.Parse(easyScoreLabel.Text);
aMessage.highScoreMedium = Int32.Parse(mediumScoreLabel.Text);
aMessage.highScoreHard = Int32.Parse(hardScoreLabel.Text);
dbcontext.messages.Add(aMessage);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is the value of `eastScoreLabel.Text`?

Comment: That's a good question. I updated the code above to show a value being assigned to easyScoreLabel.Text, but now I'm getting a DbUpdateException. Why is this happening? I attached a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/8dipdt299/full/

Comment: Any particular reason you're creating an `int`, `.ToString()`-ing it, then `Int.Parse()`-ing the string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, you're providing a string from `easyScoreLabel.Text` which isn't in a valid `int` format.

For these purposes, the `TryParse` family of methods were invented.

From [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation succeeded.

Use it like this:

```
int parsedScoreLabel;
if (!Int32.TryParse(easyScoreLabel.Text, out parsedScoreLabel))
{
    // The parsing failed, maybe notify the user of an invalid value
}

aMessage.highScoreEasy = parsedScoreLabel;
```

Comment: I'm still getting a DbUpdateException. Here's an updated screenshot with the updated code and exception happening. http://postimg.org/image/b6jlahv0b/full/